# Delete old data in ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

In earlier versions of Elk, it was recommended practice to create index names based on time events, so you would have indices contain the date and you would easily be able to remove old data by simply removing old indices based on the date.

However, this is now deprecated as they are droping timestamped indices in favor of the field approach:

```
We're deprecating timestamped indices in favor of the _field_stats API
```

This, however, now begs the question on how can I delete data older than X days/weeks if all my data is residing in a single index? Is there a way to use curator to remove older indexed data based on the timestamp/_field_stats?

Comment: For those interested, here is the underlying issue: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/4342

Comment: Also note that Kibana will continue to support querying timestamped indexes as a whole. [more info here](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/4342#issuecomment-151583410)